# Up2 board, stuck at bios password prompt with what looks like a stuck key

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I have an up2 board (a small embedded PC from Aeon), the system uses a UEFI bios (unlike most full-size boards it does not appear to support legacy mode), the system runs Ubuntu off a MSATA SSD. I am using the EP-CBUSB10P2FLT to break out the extra USB 2 connections that are provided on a small connector.

It has recently developed an issue where it gets stuck at a BIOS password prompt with what looks like a stuck key causing stuff to be continuously typed into the box.

I have tried unplugging all USB devices, but that does not help. The issue seems to be intermittent, sometimes I will get several good boots in a row, but it seems to be happening more often than not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

After unplugging the USB 2 breakout cable in desperation, despite not seeing how a breakout cable with no devices attatched could cause the issue, I noticed that the unused pin positions on the end of the connector were damaged and looking into the connector on the UP2 board showed a bent pin.

The unused pins are used for a serial console (which can be accessed with a different breakout cable). It appears that the connector damage was causing an intermittent short between the serial console transmit and receive pins which caused the continuous typing effect. After straightening the bin on the board and cutting away the smashed up part of the connector on the cable the board started working fine.